# Why does editing javascript in Chrome Developer Tools not work?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, javascript

I have Google Chrome 13.0.782.220 on my Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (64-bit).

I try to edit a JavaScript code from an external JS file in the Chrome Developer Tools Scripts pane by double-clicking on the script area. No matter how fast I click, the only effect is to select a nearby word.

Does anybody have an idea why the edit mode isn't activated?

Comment: I don't think there is a Javascript edit mode in Webkit Inspector. At best, you could use breakpoints, and trace your output.

Comment: As stated [here](http://tinyurl.com/668gz6d) (redirected from [here](http://paulirish.com/2011/a-re-introduction-to-the-chrome-developer-tools/) it *is* possible.

Comment: [This comment](http://paulirish.com/2011/a-re-introduction-to-the-chrome-developer-tools/#comment-55781) states that "Unfortunately you cannot live-edit pretty-printed JS. Maybe that'll come later." 

Dated 16th May 2011, so its pretty recent

Comment: Yes, it does work with pretty print off. Chrome is awesome

Comment: @Capt.Nemo You hit the nail. Put it as the answer so I could award you with the bounty.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Chrome Webkit Inspector does not allow you to live-edit pretty printed Javascript. Click the pretty print button (Looks like `{ }`) in the Scripts tab to disable pretty-print mode and edit it.

Source: [Introduction To Chrome Developer Tools](http://paulirish.com/2011/a-re-introduction-to-the-chrome-developer-tools/#comment-55781)

Answer (score 3):

[It's a bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=341848). You can simulate a solution by pasting the formatted code into the minified file.

Comment: feel free to tell me why you downvoted

Comment: I tried that, chrome tab stack overflow crash. Lots of bugs there

Comment: I see this is a Feature request, and is now Archived (Jul 18, 2022) with the comment:

_Realistically not going to work on this anytime soon_

Answer (score 2):

You might have hit against the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

From [Disabling cross-domain security check for AJAX development in Google Chrome](http://blog.mfabrik.com/2010/11/29/disabling-cross-domain-security-check-for-ajax-development-in-google-chrome/) :

> Start Google Chrome from command line, Ubuntu/Linux:
>
> ```
> chromium-browser --disable-web-security
> ```